# How to add attributes all the to XMLElements in Spyne Array

Tags: arrays, xml, soap, spyne

I am using spyne Array to transform a JSON list and I need to add the "id" attribute to the "referral" parent node in the final XML.

This is the final XML I am expecting:

```
<viewOutboundResponse user="rayners">
    <referral id="123">
        <status>SUBMITTED</status>
        <from>
            <outlet id="12345">ABC</outlet>
        </from>
        <to>
            <outlet id="6789">XYZ</outlet>
        </to>
        <date>2015-01-14</date>
        <client>Bloggs</client>
        <daysToExpiry>3</daysToExpiry>
    </referral>
    <referral id="456">
        <status>REJECTED</status>
        <from>
            <outlet id="101112">DEF</outlet>
        </from>
        <to>
            <outlet id="131415">S2X Demo</outlet>
        </to>
        <date>2004-01-15</date>
        <client>Gobbs</client>
        <daysToExpiry>7</daysToExpiry>
    </referral>
</viewOutboundResponse>
```

Here is my code:

```
class ReferralSummaryType(ComplexModel):
    __type_name__ = 'referral'
    type_info = {'id': XmlAttribute(Integer),
                 'status': Unicode,
                 'from': ReferralFromType,
                 'to': ReferralToType,
                 'date': Date,
                 'client': Unicode,
                 'daysToExpiry': Integer}


class OutboundResponseType(ComplexModel):
    __mixin__ = True
    referral = Array(ReferralSummaryType)
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
<viewOutboundResponse user="rayners">
    <referral>
        <referral id="123">
            <status>SUBMITTED</status>
            <from>
                <outlet id="12345">ABC</outlet>
            </from>
            <to>
                <outlet id="6789">XYZ</outlet>
            </to>
            <date>2015-01-14</date>
            <client>Bloggs</client>
            <daysToExpiry>3</daysToExpiry>
        </referral>
        <referral id="456">
            <status>REJECTED</status>
            <from>
                <outlet id="101112">DEF</outlet>
            </from>
            <to>
                <outlet id="131415">S2X Demo</outlet>
            </to>
            <date>2004-01-15</date>
            <client>Gobbs</client>
            <daysToExpiry>7</daysToExpiry>
        </referral>
    </referral>
</viewOutboundResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

So your question says

> I need to add the "id" attribute to the "referral" parent node in the
>   final XML.

Your desired output has a sequence of referral nodes without a wrapping referral node and the result you are seeing is a sequence of embedded referral nodes (each with the id attribute) but no ID on the wrapping node.

So there is a bit of a conflict there.  If it is your need to have an ID in the wrapping referral node, then I think you might need to change your response and add a class for the wrapper type:

```
class ReferralWrapperType(ComplexModel):
    __type_name__ = 'referral'
    id = XMLAttribute(Integer)
    referral = Array(ReferralSummaryType)


class OutboundResponseType(ComplexModel):
    __mixin__ = True
     referral = ReferralWrapperType
```

whereas if what you need is what is shown in what you say is the final XML that you are expecting then from the [Spyne array documentation](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/03_types.html#arrays) I am led to believe that you could perhaps try:

```
class OutboundResponseType(ComplexModel):
    __mixin__ = True
     referral = ReferralSummaryType.customize(max_occurs="unbounded")
```

Caveat - I'm very very very new to Spyne.
Edited to use max_occurs="unbounded" instead of max_occurs=float('inf') per [this spyne bug](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/pull/155).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Spyne documentation (http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/03_types.html#arrays), using

```
referral = ReferralSummaryType.customize(max_occurs="unbounded")
```

Resolved my issue.

Thanks!